# Function implementation in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to implement this function $[n,m] = a^{n+m}u[n]$ using 41×41 array, where $u[n] =1$ since all the value will be positive, and $n,m$ from 0 to 40. But it gives a wrong value.

```
N=40
M=40
a=0.9
x =zeros(41,41)
for col = 1:41
  for row = 1:41
    for k=0:N
      for i=0:M
        x(row,col)=a.^(k+i)*1;
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This is not a signal processing question, but a Matlab basic programming question. There's a specific close reason that clarifies that these are off-topic here, but can be asked (if appropriate there) on Stackoverflow.com.

Answer (score 3):

I believe this will do:

```
x=a.^((0:40)+(0:40)’)
```

Comment: +1 for the 'expanding vector' Matlab sum (weird as it may seem)

Comment: See this blog post for an interesting discussion on this «implicit expansion» behaviour: https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/10/24/matlab-arithmetic-expands-in-r2016b/

Answer (score 0):

```
N=40;
M=40;
a=0.9;
x =zeros(M+1,N+1)
for n = 0:N
  for m = 0:M 
    % add 1 for Matlab's indexing offset
    x(n+1,m+1)=a.^(m+n)*1;
  end
end
```

If you want to fix your code as written try this. You have too many loops, you only need two. Knut's code is a lot faster and more efficient though